# Why won't my footer show up in the right area? Can I affect the CSS?

Tags: html, css

On my website, christianselig.com, my footer shows up on all the pages except the about.html page (http://christianselig.com/about.html) in which it shows up near the top for some reasons.

The page consists of two floated divs (one left, one right) with a div wrapping both, and I realize the floats are probably the issue, but I have no idea what to do. Relevant CSS and HTML can be found below, and further stuff is obviously available right on the website.

HTML:

```
<div class="footer-wrapper">
            <div class="footer">
                <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2012 Christian Selig</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer-wrapper {
    background: #f7f7f7; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f7f7f7 0%, #d6d6d6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f7f7f7), color-stop(100%,#d6d6d6)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f7f7f7 0%,#d6d6d6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #f7f7f7 0%,#d6d6d6 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #f7f7f7 0%,#d6d6d6 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f7f7f7 0%,#d6d6d6 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f7f7f7', endColorstr='#d6d6d6',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 15px auto 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 8px 0 5px 0;
}

    .footer {
        color: #808080;
        clear: both;
        font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 0.7em;
        width: 900px; 
    }

        .copyright {
            float: left;
            margin: 0 0 5px 60px;
        }

        .footer ul {
            float: right;
            margin: 0 60px 5px 0;
        }

        .footer li {
            display: inline;
            padding-right: 12px;
        }

            .footer li:last-child {
                padding-right: 0;
            }

        .footer a {
            color: #808080;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .footer a:hover, .footer a:active {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would guess there's an issue with the DOM structure on that page in particular.  I would look at the site itself but it's ridiculously slow in loading atm.

Comment: Surely not all of that CSS is really relevant to the positioning. The font / color / background stuff might as well go.

Comment: Would a     position: absolute;bottom: 0; work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to add the following, along with the existing styles:

```
.lr-wrapper { overflow:hidden; }
```

*[more info](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html#link3)*

Comment: What exactly does this do? Conceptually speaking.

Comment: basically triggers the div to have a layout and effect the flow of the page ... http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html#link3

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is inside `lr-wrapper`. Your two elements `left-side` and `right-side` doesn't fill the whole width, leaving a space in between for other floating elements to fit.

You need to add a `clear` before the footer to tell all other elements to stay below, you can do it by adding this just above the footer div:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

or you can do it the right way, by adding this to your css and then be able to just apply the class `clearfix` when you need something to break the floating:

```
/*
 * Clearfix: contain floats
 *
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    `contenteditable` attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that receive the `clearfix` class.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

/*
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

More info on this can be found here: http://html5boilerplate.com/

Comment: @Xander: Sure, but it's not really the right way to go, when the real problem is he have two floating elements: `left-side` and `right-side` with a gap in between. So you need to tell every other floating element to end up under these, how ever much place there is in between.

Comment: to clear other element, you tell the footer to `clear:both`, which will clear previously floated elements ... OR you make the floated elements take up the full width of the container making the floated elements that follow clear previously floated elements implicitly ...